# Docker + IdentityServer4. Ошибка подключения

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, httpclient, identityserver4

Есть настроенный IdentityServer4 на Asp.Net core 3. К нему консольный клиент, клиент запрашивает и получает токен следующим образом

```
       private static async Task<string> GetToken(string address)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(address);
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
            return default;
        }

        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest ...
```

При работе с адресами localhost, 127.0.0.1 - все замечательно. Как только сервер оказывается в докер-контейнере с адресом, например, 192.168.99.100(docker-machine) - появляется следующая ошибка: "Error connecting to http://192.168.99.100:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration. HTTPS required.".

При этом в браузере открывается нормально, видимо проблема в HttpClient. Есть ли какой-либо известный способ решить проблему без прикручивания https? Видел решение с использованием DiscoveryClient в документации:

```
var client = new DiscoveryClient("http://dev.identityserver.internal");
client.Policy.RequireHttps = false;

var disco = await client.GetAsync();
```

Но то ли я дурак, то ли из пространства имен IdentityModel этот клиент куда то пропал

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47019923